# MediaRecorder produces jaudiotagger CannotReadException

Tags: android, tags, audio-recording, jaudiotagger

I am creating a m4a file with MediaRecorder as follows:

```
    recorder2 = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder2.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder2.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder2.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    recorder2.setAudioEncodingBitRate(128000);
    recorder2.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
    recorder2.setOutputFile(<fullFilePath.m4a>);
```

It works perfectly. After the file is created, I want to add ID3 tags to it using jaudiotagger. So I do:

```
    AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(new File(<fullFilePath.m4a>));
    Tag fileTag = f.getTag();
    fileTag.setField(FieldKey.COMMENT,"AVE Tags:.....");
```

This is working great with WAV files generated with AudioRecord, but for m4a files generated as above with MediaRecorder I get an exception in the AudioFile line:

```
W/System.err: org.jaudiotagger.audio.exceptions.CannotReadException: <fullFilePath.m4a>:
Unable to find next atom because identifier is invalid ��������
```

I also tried with

```
Mp4FileReader reader = new Mp4FileReader();
AudioFile f = reader.read(new File(AveActivity.REC_DIR,song));
....
```

but I get the same error... What's wrong?

BTW, I am using implementation 'com.github.goxr3plus:jaudiotagger:2.2.7'
(Why so many versions? Isn't this quite dangerous??)

**EDIT**:

There are several things that I do not like about this, so I decided to ditch `jaudiotagger` altogether. It doesn't make sense to use this heavy, buggy, and hard-to-track-a-trusty-version of it for android. So I made my own tiny thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72157624/1483390) for WAVE files that works perfectly right after `AudioRecord`, and without the need to open/close/save the file twice.

Yet, I am not deleting the post since the first half shows that there is something strange with `jaudiotagger` for m4a, at least with the version I got from `goxr3plus`.

Comment: Can you replace `SampleRate` and `song` with their raw values so it's clear what is being sent to MediaRecorder?

Comment: Updated. `song` is just the full path to the m4a, and `SampleRate` is the usual 44100.